# How to retrofit Non Generic based EF Core code to use Generic IQueryable

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-core-3.1, .net-6.0, ef-core-6.0

I am updating an old EF solution to EF Core and I would like to remove much of the code that is not using generics (T) but I have to do it in stages.  The original code is suffering from organic growth of learning entity framework over 10 years and is a mix of "philosophies" and patterns from the code like in the tutorials from Microsoft to Repository pattern.

The ideal solution would be something that would allow me to build up the query for a particular entity then open the connection and run the "ToList()".  I can then move parts of the code in stages to something cleaner.

```
//logic to figure out what is needed with no connection or dbconnection yet
public void GetOrder(){
     var query = new List<Order>().AsQueryable();
     query = query.Where(x => x.Id > 100);
     var orders = repo.GetItems<Order>(query);
}

public IEnumerable<T> GetItems<T>(IQueryable<T> query, int page = 0, int maxcount = 0)
        {
            using (MyEntities context = new MyEntities(getConnectionString()))
            {
                context.Attach(query); //This does not seem to work
                if (page > 1)
                    query = query.Skip(page * maxcount);
                if (maxcount > 0)
                    query = query.Take(maxcount);

                return query.ToList();
            }
        }
```

In the original older code the EF repository was initializing the entities in the code/request constructor then it was calling the above method GetItems.  It looked like two different connections were being made to the database and two different Entity initializations were happening to make 1 request to the database.

I am using EF Core 6 and .NET 6 (Core 6).

Comment: EF Core should not open connection until you materialize the query (i.e. run `ToList` or any other "analog").

Comment: EF Core is by definition generic. DbSet<T> is generic and implements `IQueryable<T>`. What are you trying to do? Implement paging? You don't even need a reference to a DbContext for that. Why are you using `context.Attach(query);` at all? This is used to attach data classes, not execute queries

Comment: Is the real problem that the code is using the "generic repository" *anti*-pattern (quotes and smallcase intentional) so it controllers have trouble using `IQueryable<T>` or `DbContext` perhaps? Even so, no matter how the repository is implemented, it's *its* job to get a DbContext instance. BTW a DbSet already implements Repository. DbContext implements Unit of Work

Answer (score 0):

You use `context.Set<T>()` to get the `DbSet<T>` (which is already an `IQueryable<T>`).

`context.Attach` attaches entities to the change tracker of the context, which is not what you want.

So you want something like:

```
public void GetOrders(){
    List<Order> orders;
    using(MyEntities context = new MyEntities(getConnectionString()))
    {
       var query = new List<Order>().AsQueryable();
       orders = context.GetItems<Order>().Where(x => x.Id > 100).ToList();    
    }
    // Do whatever with "orders", which is already materialized and doesn't need the dbcontext instance anymore
}


public static class DbContextExtensions
{
    // On some extension static class
    public static IQueryable<T> GetItems<T>(this MyEntities context, int page = 0, int maxcount = 0)
    where T: class
    {
        var query = context.Set<T>().AsQueryable();
        if (page > 1)
            query = query.Skip(page * maxcount);
        if (maxcount > 0)
            query = query.Take(maxcount);

        return query;
    }
}
```

Note that this is way out of how you should use dbcontext's these days (there's dependency injection, async, etc.), but I'm basing on the code you posted on the question

Answer (score 0):

You can build `Func<IQueryable<T>, IQueryable<T>>` and use `context.Set<T>()` method. Something along this lines:

```
public void GetOrder(){
     Func<IQueryable<Order>, IQueryable<Order>> queryProvider = 
     query => query.Where(x => x.Id > 100);
     var orders = repo.GetItems<Order>(query);
}

public IEnumerable<T> GetItems<T>(Func<IQueryable<T>, IQueryable<T>> queryProvider, int page = 0, int maxcount = 0)
{
    using (MyEntities context = new MyEntities(getConnectionString()))
    {
         var query = queryProvider(context.Set<T>()); 
         if (page > 1)
            query = query.Skip(page * maxcount);
         if (maxcount > 0)
            query = query.Take(maxcount);

         return query.ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

Note that manually creating `DbContext`'s is not an idiomatic approach anymore, usually it is handled by DI.

Also I would recommend just to create an `Paginate` extension method. Something like this:

```cs
public static class QueryableExt
{
    public static IQueryable<T> Paginate<T>(this IQueryable<T> query, int page = 0, int maxcount = 0)
    {
        if (page > 1)
            query = query.Skip(page * maxcount);
        if (maxcount > 0)
            query = query.Take(maxcount);
        return query;
    }
}
```

Comment: There's no reason to use DbContet at all. That paging method (that's what it is) can be build simply on top `IQueryable<>`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos yes, sure. Was just adding the code.

Answer (score 0):

The code's problem isn't generics - by definition, EF Core is generic. `DbSet<T>` and `IQueryable<T>` are generic. All operators are generic.

The problem is mixing up two things. Paging over an IQueryable and creating a specific IQueryable implementation. If you split these two into separate parts, the problem becomes very easy.

The paging method can be :

```
public static IQueryable<T> GetPage<T>(this IQueryable<T> query,int page,int maxcount)
{
    if (page > 1)
        query = query.Skip(page * maxcount);
    if (maxcount > 0)
        query = query.Take(maxcount);
    return query;
 }
```

This can be used with any `IQueryable<T>` implementation, whether it's a container implementing `IEnumerable<T>` like a `List<T>` or an EF Core query:

```
var myList=new List<Order>();
...
var query=myList.AsQueryable()
                .Where(...)
                .GetPage(2,10);
var pageOrders=query.ToList();
```

Or

```
var query=context.Orders
                 .Where(...)
                 .GetPage(2,10);
var pageOrders=query.ToList();
```

There's no reason to create a `GetItems` method, as all it does is create a *specific* DbContext and use a *specific* DbSet. There's no need to hide `context.Orders` or the code that creates `context`. In fact, in environments with dependency injection like ASP.NET Core, that DbContext will be injected by the DI container